# WPF Docking like chrome?

Tags: wpf, docking

I'm trying to find a docking library for WPF that works more like google chrome. Where a user with two chrome windows open can take a tab from one and drop it in another.

I've been trying with AvalonDock but it only lets a DockableContent have one docking manager and I can't find a nice way to swap the manager when it moves over a different one.

Anyone know of a way to do this with AvalonDock or any other library?

Comment: Still no reply, guess I'll have to build something. Thought this would have been tackled already.

Comment: To update  this there now is a solution: https://github.com/ButchersBoy/Dragablz

Answer (score 1):

I think that your requirements are a bit too special purpose just to find a library lying about.  It sounds like AvalonDock does kind of what you want, so maybe it would be best just to modify its source for your needs.  That or just roll your own from scratch.